# Avoid timeout with Jade Db source connection in SSIS task

Tags: ssis, odbc

I've got an SSIS job that pulls GL transactions from a Jade database via ODBC. If I have a large date range of transactions, I get a read timeout from Jade. Is there a way to structure an SSIS job so that it would pull a few days at a time in separate reads from the source, so that it avoids this timeout. I'm using a for loop and only asking for a few days at a time but it fails, so I've obviously not avoided the issue.

To be clear we're going to up the timeout on the server from 3 to 10 minutes. We won't use a 0 timeout for obvious reasons but there is always a chance that if we need to pull a large range of data for a new project we'd hit whatever reasonable timeout we set.

I'm looking for a way to structure the job to incrementally pull smaller ranges until it's complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the timeout setting, it's on the Jade Dataflow Component, not on the ODBC connection object where I thought it would be. I probably put a value in there when I created the package about 18 months ago, and forgot about it.